# Why doesn't Māui fly over Te Kā instead of fighting and getting through it?

Tags: plot-explanation, moana

While Māui could not fly through Te Kā in his giant hawk form to get to Te Fiti **before** the incident where his magical fish hook was severely damaged <s>by the overpowered brofist with Te Kā</s>, I can see he flies relatively close to the surface of the ocean.

Why doesn't Māui just fly higher and fly over Te Kā <s>(ggez)</s>, so Te Kā can't reach him by slamming him with its hand? Of course, the throwing fireball skill is an exception in this case. Instead of that he spent so much efforts to fight and get through Te Kā?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but even if he passes through Te Ka ,Since Te Ka is itself Te fi ti , he couldnt have been successful, Only smart kid like Moana can do the task :p

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself: **fireball**.

And if he flies too high to save himself from fireballs then what is the point? He still needs to get down to do the task.

Comment: The point is, he somehow could not dodge the slamming attacks from Te Kā and ends up went into the sea. But he could dodge the fireballs before getting close enough to Te Kā. The fireballs don't really matter, as long as Māui flies over Te Kā in order not to getting slammed into the sea.

Comment: @BoostedNub didn't he had issues within his power some time back?

Comment: Presumably the issue he had was transforming, which doesn't relevant to my concern.

Comment: @BoostedNub my point is out of practice

Comment: @Boosted Nub Come on it's an animated movie. Why are you considering good tactical efficiency?

Comment: @BoostedNub: At range, you can dodge a fireball because you can see its trajectory and dodge it. The closer you get, the less time you have to see the trajectory and avoid it. Secondly, the accuracy of Te Ka will drop off with range, making it less likely to actually get hit.